# Approaches for implementing Resilient Business Flows

Tags: frameworks, microservices, workflow, distributed-system, saga

I have been working extensively on an open-source workflow-as-code framework (https://github.com/stidsborg/Cleipnir.Flows) for a couple of years and have been wondering lately what different approaches exists for handling code which needs to be executed in its entirety.

The goto use-case for resilient code is order-processing. Here one must ensure that the order is completely processed despite any process restarts/crashes.

For instance, consider the following simplified flow:

```
ProcessOrder(Order order)
  PaymentProvider.ReserveFunds
  LogisticsService.ShipProducts
  PaymentProvider.CaptureFunds
  EmailService.SendOrderConfirmation
```

I.e. if the process executing the ProcessOrder-method crashes after ShipProducts has been called but before CaptureFunds, then the customer receives the products without paying.

It seems to me that the following approaches can be taken:

1. Job-Scheduler (Hangfire/Quartz)
2. Vanilla message queue (RabbitMQ, Azure ServiceBus)
3. Message Queue with Routing Slip (temporary flow state is kept in messages)
4. ServiceBus (MassTransit, NServiceBus, Rebus)
5. Workflow-as-Code (Azure Durable Functions, temporal.io)

Am I missing any?